# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "erwarten" und "warten"?

Tags: word-usage

Wie kann man einem Franzosen den Unterschied zwischen ***erwarten*** und ***warten*** erklären?

Im Französischen nutzt man für beide Wörter *attendre*.

Als Beispiel bereiten mir besonders *das Erwarten eines Gastes* und *das Warten auf einen Gast* Kopfschmerzen.

Answer (score 10):

Well, *warten* is the state of doing nothing until a certain condition is fulfilled<sup>1</sup>.
*Warten* is intransitive. This means, you don't apply an object to it. Hence, you don't know what you are waiting for. If you, however, want to add this information, you can use the preposition *auf* and add the object or you use *erwarten*, which is transitive and expects an object.

The subtle difference between *warten auf* and *erwarten* is that the latter one does not really convey the idea of doing nothing until the condition is fulfilled. It's more like looking forward to something happening. Thus, you can say *Ich erwarte einen Gast* a week before they arrive, but you would say *Ich warte auf meinen Gast* a couple of minutes before they arrive.

Last but not least, don't forget that both words have one other meaning. *Warten* can also mean *to repair* and *erwarten* has also the meaning of *to demand*, which is also true for the English word *to expect*.

---

<sup>1</sup> Of course, you often fill up the waiting time with doing some minor things that you can stop at any time.

Answer (score 1):

Wenn der Franzose Englisch kann: warten auf = to wait for, erwarten = to expect (not in the pregnancy sense).

Comment: Ich glaube "der Franzone" hat das gleiche Problem mit expect/wait, aber ich kann's probieren.

Comment: @PatrickB I'm not great at German, but based on this answer, maybe *warten auf* = *attendre* and *erwarten* = *s'attendre à*?